# get Player Name from SteamID

Tags: javascript, php, steam-web-api

I'm Creating a Loading Screen for a game server for Garry's Mod.
I need a way to convert the users SteamID or CommunityID to their name.
AKA `STEAM_0:1:48093934 -> NightmareInfinity` or `76561198056453597 -> NightmareInfinity`

Im currently using PHP and JavaScript to convert.
If you need the function names i have
`SteamID2Communityid($steamid)`
and
`CommunityID2SteamID($communityid)`
Both functions are in PHP

I have also looked at other questions, None of them helped me.

I looked at the SteamAPI and couldn't find anything.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Comment: Have you checked out the steam API? https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#Public_Data with this you obtain the display name (personaname)

Comment: look at the function GetPlayerSummaries()     
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old php function of mine should still work.

```
function EchoPlayerName($steamid){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");//link to user xml
    if(!empty($xml)) {
        $username = $xml->steamID;
        echo $username;
    }
}
```